# XSL checking and output Nodes that have Duplicate Elements Values

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, element

I'm currently trying to output a list containing all the nodes having a duplicate  element value. Following is my source XML and XLS:

**Source XML**

```
<menu>
    <game name="Alien Ambush (USA)" index="" image="">
        <description>Alien Ambush (USA)</description>
        <cloneof></cloneof>
        <crc>34634E16</crc>
        <manufacturer>Micro Distributors</manufacturer>
        <year>1982</year>
        <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
        <rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
        <enabled>Yes</enabled>
    </game>
    <game name="Alien Game (USA)" index="" image="">
        <description>Alien Game (USA)</description>
        <cloneof></cloneof>
        <crc>34634E16</crc>
        <manufacturer>-</manufacturer>
        <year>19xx</year>
        <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
        <rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
        <enabled>Yes</enabled>
    </game>
    <game name="Alien Invasion (USA)" index="" image="">
        <description>Alien Invasion (USA)</description>
        <cloneof></cloneof>
        <crc>20679D78</crc>
        <manufacturer>Programma Software</manufacturer>
        <year>1979</year>
        <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
        <rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
        <enabled>Yes</enabled>
    </game>
    <game name="Night Survival (USA)" index="" image="">
        <description>Night Survival (USA)</description>
        <cloneof></cloneof>
        <crc>34634E16</crc>
        <manufacturer>-</manufacturer>
        <year>19xx</year>
        <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
        <rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
        <enabled>Yes</enabled>
    </game>
</menu>
```

**Desired Output**

```
Alien Ambush (USA),34634E16
Alien Game (USA),34634E16
Night Survival (USA),34634E16
```

I'm currently using the following XLS, which works but it will omit the final node having the duplicate  value.

**Current XLS**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="game" >
        <xsl:if test="(following::game[crc=current()/crc])">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="crc"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
Alien Ambush (USA),34634E16
Alien Game (USA),34634E16
```

Notice that I'm actually using a comma since I will then feed this as csv into Excel to sort according to the CRC value. It would be great if I could also sort the  key using XLS. I also tried to output into the following and apply the following XLS to sort by crc, but the outcome remains the same.

**Output**

```
<game name="Alien Ambush (USA)">
    <crc>34634E16</crc>
</game>
<game name="Alien Game (USA)">
    <crc>34634E16</crc>
</game>
```

**Sorting XLS by CRC**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>



    <xsl:template match="game" >
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="crc"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would be helpful if someone could give me some pointer. I'm still relatively new to XLS.

Comment: So what is the actual result format that you want - assuming it can all be done within XSLT (as I believe it can)?

Comment: Hi there michael. The end result should be something similar to the Desired Output but having the node sorted according to the <crc> value. It sure sounds like possible using XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/menu">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="game" group-by="crc">
            <xsl:sort select="crc" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) > 1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="game">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="crc"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmm I tried to apply the transformation but it seemed to be invalid.

Comment: @D.Sync I don't know what "seemed to be invalid" means.  You can see the transformation working here: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFM -- Note that the results are actually sorted by `crc` - but you need to have at least two groups in order to see this.

Comment: I'm actually using both the NotePad++ XML plugin and EditX Free Edition to apply the XLS transformation. NotePad++ just shows that the template was invalid while the EditX gives me the error "xsl:sort must be child of xsl:apply-templates or xsl:for-each". It's strange why the web app that you are using works though hmm

Comment: The strange thing is why is **your** stylesheet tagged  `version="2.0"` when you are using a processor (NotePad++ ) that only supports XSLT 1.0. I am not sure about EditX - doesn't it allow you to select an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I didn't realize that NotePad++ is using XSLT1.0 processor. Tested on XSLT2.0 processor and it works perfectly. Thanks!